# How to align image with radio button?

Tags: css

I have 3 images of mXn pixels(approx), but on rendering, the image size increase due to zoom-in issue, as shown below:

[image]

Below is the html code,

```
<div class="cardtype">
                <label>Cardtype:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="visa"><img src="visa.png"> VISA
                <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="amex"><img src="amex.png"> AMEX
                <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="mastercard"><img src="mastercard.png"> Master card
</div>
```

Below is the CSS code,

```
.cardtype input{
                width: 8%;
            }
.cardtype img{
                width: 8%;
            }
```

How do I align `img` and `input` radio button horizontally?

Is this something to do with image size? How do I decide the image size?

Is this something to do with image resolution? How do I decide the image resolution?

Comment: can use "vertical-align" property to align top, bottom or middle

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bootply.com/pYw1JhTXOW

Try to set size to image wrappers, not to images directly.

Comment: OK, got it. But how do I decide the size of images(downloaded)? Currently  the image size is 658x202 px. Is that not an issue?

Comment: Try to resize this page http://www.bootply.com/render/Zl4ShJI2p8
Source code: http://www.bootply.com/Zl4ShJI2p8

Comment: ya but try to take amex/mastercard/visa images, you will find the results different. In your case you tried with 3 images(VISA.png) of same size

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can take radio button in label and make some padding to that image within label, for example :-

```
<div class="cardtype">
    <label>Cardtype:</label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="visa"><img src="visa.png"> VISA
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="amex"><img src="amex.png"> AMEX
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="mastercard"><img src="mastercard.png"> Master card
    </label>
</div>
```

Now do some css for that image :-

```
.radio img{
   padding-top : 5px; //take as per your img these just for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (use vertical-align):

**CSS**

```
.cardtype img{
    width: 8%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/8eae8z9L/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it. This will work for any image size.

Add the span around the image to help position it I gave it the class helper, you will also need to add a bit of css.

add this css:

```
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 8%;
}
.helper img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
}
```

try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kLbvh139/

Comment: what do you mean? yes I was the output, it looks fine to me